# porta serial node.js

Tags: node.js, interface, serial

Preciso escrever um código para **node.js** que receba um "post request" (neste caso uma palavra `String`), e passe esta palavra adiante para porta serial. Depois recebe desta porta serial outra palavra e coloca esta palavra como resposta para um "post request".

Deve ser um código simples, mas eu não entendo muito de **node.js** e já li muita informação e vários tutoriais, mas não achei como exatamente fazer o que eu preciso.

Eu preciso disso para finalizar meu pequeno aplicativo (eu esto longe de ser uma programadora web) e não consigo achar exemplos nessesários no meio de tanta informação.

O máximo que eu consegui escrever foi:

```js
var express = require('express')

var app = express()

app.get('/notes', function(req, res) {
  res.json({
    notes: "World"
  })
})

app.listen(3000)



var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}))

app.post('/notes', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.notes || typeof req.body.notes != "string") {
    res.status(400).send("400 Bad Request")
  }

  req.user.customData.notes = req.body.notes
  req.user.customData.save()
  res.status(200).end()
})
```

E não sei como modificar isto para que trabalhe com porta serial.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport